# fastest way to get MPMediaItem with no album data

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

Im looking for the faster way to grab all songs from my iOS music library that do not belong to an album.

I know essentially I can traverse through all the tracks and check for an album title. But I was looking a better way, maybe use a predicate of something like this...

```
[[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Unknown Album" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle]];
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastest way I found is by settings a predicate on the `[MPMediaQuery songsQuery]`

```
[[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"0" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID]];
```